# XをYという形に sentence

Tags: grammar, word-choice, loanwords

> 「俺焼き豚頼んでないですよ」
> 店主であり違法改造バイク夢五萬のライダーである高田くんのお兄さんは、**菜ばしを“サービス”という形に動かした**。
>
> "I did not order pork loin."
> Takada's brother, who is the shop owner and rides an illegally modified motorcycle "Dream50000", said the chopsticks were "service" and moved them to that shape?

What does that bold part mean?

Comment: サービス means 'freebie' here.

Comment: Hint 2: Does changing the word order help: “サービス”という形に、菜ばしを動かした

Comment: So does this mean something like: He changed the copsticks in the shape of "freebie" (Kind of like he made that gesture with the copsticks to show it's a freebie). Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that matches with how I understand it. I just haven't a clue what sort of stick gesture means サービス

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you figured it out, but I'll make a proper answer since nobody else seems to be writing one.

> 高田くんのお兄さんは、菜ばしを“サービス”という形に動かした。
>
> 高田くんのお兄さんは *Takada's brother* -- subject
>
> 菜ばしを *chopsticks* -- object
>
> 動かした *moved* -- verb
>
> 高田くんのお兄さんは、菜ばしを動かした。 *Takada's brother moved (his) chopsticks*
>
> “サービス”という[形]{かたち}に *into the shape of* 「サービス」

サービス means 'freebie' in this context. He was making a gesture with his chopsticks to inform that the food was "on the house".

What that gesture looks like, I don't know. If someone happens to know, please comment.

Comment: What is meant is probably that he moved the chopsticks in the air (or on some surface, it's not possible to say for sure) as if to "write" the letters 「サ」「ー」「ビ」「ス」 － of which movement 「菜ばしを“サービス”という形に動かした」 isn't really a good way to express. Something like 「菜ばしで宙に"サービス"と書いた」 might have been more clear and fitting.

Comment: @oals Thank you, I still have troubles understanding when a subclauses modifies a noun. For example:高田くんのお兄さんは、菜ばしを“サービス”という形に動かした。I would have tought it was [菜ばしを“サービス”という]>形に動かした while you said it's サービス”という形に.

Comment: @Splikie ＸというＹ is a very common way of saying or specifying *"X, which is a Y"* or more naturally *"the Y of 'X'"* and should be parsed as a single unit.